# moment.js: how to get short date format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My application sends an HTML file with javascript like this:

```
$(function () {
    moment.locale('fr');
    $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years',
        locale: 'fr',
        format: '' /* <========= problem! */
    });
});
```

With moment, when I set to a locale, is there a way to get the short date format of the configuration like "`'j F Y'`" for `fr`?

I found it but it's hack-ish:

```
moment()['_locale']['_longDateFormat']['L']
```

So my code now:

```
$(function () {
    moment.locale('fr');
    $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years',
        locale: 'fr',
        format: moment()['_locale']['_longDateFormat']['L']
    });
});
```

I dont like that, is there a clean way to get the format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve locale-specific format strings with the `longDateFormat()` of [the current `localeData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/):

```
moment.locale('fr');

var localeData = moment.localeData();
var dateFormat = localeData.longDateFormat('LL');

console.log(dateFormat); // D MMMM YYYY
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for the date formats??  I have scoured the moment.js docs and find references to them but no definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Later versions of moment.js have localised formatting available - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

> Localized formats
>
> Because preferred formatting differs based on locale, there are a few
> tokens that can be used to format a moment based on its locale.
>
> There are upper and lower case variations on the same formats. The
> lowercase version is intended to be the shortened version of its
> uppercase counterpart.
>
> Time  LT  8:30 PM
>
> Time with seconds LTS 8:30:25 PM
>
> Month numeral, day of month, year L   09/04/1986
>
> l 9/4/1986
>
> Month name, day of month, year LL September 4 1986 ll Sep 4 1986
>
> Month name, day of month, year, time  LLL September 4 1986 8:30 PM
>
> lll   Sep 4 1986 8:30 PM
>
> Month name, day of month, day of week, year, time LLLL    Thursday, September 4 1986 8:30 PM
>
> llll  Thu, Sep 4 1986 8:30 PM
>
> L LL LLL LLLL LT are available in
> version 1.3.0. l ll lll llll are available in 2.0.0. LTS was added in
> 2.8.4.

So you can get the localised short date format with:

```
var formattedDate = moment(d).format("l");
```

Comment: The question is with respect to accessing the format strings, as opposed to using MomentJS to format date values.